# Not able to add new user to IAM in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I want to change the email address that is shown in google OAuth flow for Firebase Auth. For that, I need to add that email address to IAM in GCP. But, I can't see the option to add a new user. This is what I see:

[image]

Docs say there should be a `Grant access` button but there isn't. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/grant-role-console
[image]

Comment: I had the same thing happen today, the button was there earlier in the day but now not seeing it.